# Would it be good to use a singleton context on a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, dbcontext, singleton-type

I read in some places that it would be good to use a singleton context, but what if it was in a service? It will keep running all the time, making from time to time requests to a REST API, so I'm thinking, it will have an instance of the `DbContext` allocated on the memory.

What would be better, the using `(var context = new DbContext())` or a singleton `DbContext`?

Answer (score 2):

`DbContext` is cheap, and there is some housekeeping that occurs when they are created and disposed. Don't use a singleton for one.